# What does this definition of an $H$-path mean?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm going through *Graph Theory* by Reinhard Diestel, [which](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch1.pdf) defines an *$H$-path* as follows:

> Given a graph $H$, we call $P$ an *$H$-path* if $P$ is non-trivial and meets $H$ exactly in its ends. In particular, the edge of any $H$-path of length $1$ is never an edge of $H$.

Please could somebody help me understand what this means?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can think of $P$ and $H$ as being subgraphs of a larger graph. Here's another version of what I think is intended by Diestel there:

If $H$ is a subgraph of $G$, then a path $P$ in $G$ is an *$H$-path* if the endpoints of $P$ are in $H$ and none of the other vertices or edges are in $H$.

[image]