# 2-connected graph game

Tags: graph-theory

*Problem 7.2.53* in Combinatorial Mathematics by Douglas B. West.

1. Complete question is:

Alice and Bob play a game on 2-connected $n$-vertex graph $G$. Alice picks vertices $u$ and $v$. Next Bob orients up to $f(n)$ of the edges. Alice then orients the remaining edges and selects an edge $e$, which may have been oriented by her or by Bob. If the orientation contains a $u,v$-path through $e$, then Bob wins; otherwise Alice wins. Prove that the least $f(n)$ such that Bob always has a winning strategy is $2n - 3$. (Kerimov [2009]).

2. My effort:

I am trying to consider the construction of 2-connected graph:

> (Proposition) A graph is 2-connected if and only if it can be constructed from a cycle by successively adding $H$-paths to graph $H$ already constructed.

But I can not determine the edges I really need. Please give me some hint if possible!

Comment: Orienting here means re-arranging the edges between the vertices? Also, what is your proposition saying? What does "adding $H$-paths to graph $H$ already constructed" means?

Comment: I think it means that constructing an [Orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(graph_theory)) from the undirected graph $G$; And for $H$-path, there is a [definition and explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078811/what-does-this-definition-of-an-h-path-mean/1078900), maybe it will help you understand.

Comment: The book also has a hint for this problem. Are you familiar with the notion of an $st$-numbering?

Comment: Before trying to determine how many edges (or which edges) Bob need to orient, what conditions can we give on the arcs oriented by Bob for Alice not to win? That is, what could Alice play given a partially oriented $G$?

Comment: @ Dániel G. I try to find some hint on the textbook but failed. And I find the definition of $st$-numbering on wiki , it is great and I will try to think in that way :)

Comment: @ Guyslain Sorry, could you please explain more?

Comment: I think this problem is quite hard, and you should first try solving simpler questions to get an understanding of where to go. I suggest trying to find what could be Alice winning moves, and then from that find necessary conditions for the partial orientation chosen by Bob. This will likely help in  determining how many edges Bob need to orient.

Comment: @ Guyslain Thank you! And I have post a solution by my TA, hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

(Original answer by my TA, really impressive)

First, we can use triangle $(n=3)$ show that $2n-4$ is not enough: for any two vertices $u,v$, if Bob choose $uv$ and another edge $uw$, then Alice just needs to choose $vw$ as $e$ and orient it such that $u-w-v$ can not be a path; if Bob choose $uw$ and $vw$, then Alice only needs to orient $uv$ as $v-u$ and choose $e$ as $vu$.

Now we prove that Bob always has a winning strategy when he can orient $2n-3$ edges. For that, we need to prove a $s,t$-numbering lemma:

> *Exercise 7.2.51* in Combinatorial Mathematics by Douglas B. West.
> Let $s$ and $t$ be vertices in a 2-connected graph $G$. Prove that the vertices of $G$ can be linearly ordered so that each vertex outside $\{s,t\}$ has a neighbor that is earlier in the order and a neighbor that is later in the order. (Comment: This is called an $s,t$-numbering of $G$.)

(To be done)

Then the vertices of $G$ can be linearly ordered so that each vertex other than $u,v$ has a neighbor that is earlier in order and a neighbor that is later in order.

If $uv \in G$ then Bob orients it from $u$ to $v$. For any vertex $w$ other than $u, v$, pick its smallest neighbor $s$ and largest neighbour $t$. Bob orients $s w$ from $s$ to $w$ and orients $w t$ from $w$ to $t$. These add up to no more than $1+2\times(n-2)=2n-3$ edges. Next we prove there is always a $u, v$-path through $e$. If $e$ is oriented by Bob, then we may extend both ends following Bob's orientation and eventually we will reach $u$ and $v$. If $e$ is oriented by Alice from the smaller endpoint to the larger one then the same method works. And finally, if $e$ is oriented from $x$ to $y$ where $x>y$, then this fact itself shows that $x$ has a neighbor $x^{\prime}$ smaller than $y$ and $y$ has a neighbor $y^{\prime}$ larger than $x$. So we may follow Bob's orientation from $u$ to $x$ through $x^{\prime}$, go from $x$ to $y$ and then follow Bob's orientation from $y$ to $v$ through $y^{\prime}$. Since $x^{\prime}<y$ and $y^{\prime}>x$, the trail we constructed above is indeed a path.